# Does anyone knows how TeamViewer gets screen capturing?

Tags: android, screen-capture, teamviewer

I'm looking for an way to record my Android's screen without rooting my phone. This will be on my work phone, so I'm not allowed to root it.

I recently found TeamViewer QuickSupport which lets you control an Android phone remotely, Surely someone's made an app that uses the same API that TeamViewer uses to retrieve the screen ?

I mean, TeamViewer is recording it and sending it over wifi with no trouble, so why do actual screen recording apps require root?

Does anyone knows how that tool gets screen capturing ?

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

getting from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content

> Use the following code:
>
> ```
> Bitmap bitmap; View v1 = MyView.getRootView();
> v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); bitmap =
> Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
> v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); Here MyView is the View through
> which we need include in the screen. You can also get DrawingCache
> from of any View this way (without getRootView()).
>
>
> There is also another way.. If we having ScrollView as root view then
> its better to use following code,
>
> LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
> this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); FrameLayout root =
> (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null); //
> activity_main is UI(xml) file we used in our Activity class.
> FrameLayout is root view of my UI(xml) file.
> root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); Bitmap bitmap =
> getBitmapFromView(this.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.frameLayout)); //
> here give id of our root layout (here its my FrameLayout's id)
> ```

Comment: Hello ArcherGodson, Thank you, But I know this way is useful if you want to take a screen shot of your own view, I am looking for a way to get any (other apps) activity's screen shot without having root permissions.